# How can configure Glassfish server 5.1 not to disclose environment information

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

We recently performed a PCI scan and one of the suggestion was that environment information shouldn't be disclosed. Does anyone have idea how to configure Glassfish server not disclose the server information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to settings in the response headers. If so, you need to make three configuration changes, so start Glassfish and open its Administration Console. That's http://localhost:4848 in my case, but you may have something different.

Change 1:

- Select **Configurations > server-config > JVM Settings**, then click the **JVM Options** tab.
- Click the **Add JVM Option** button. Add the option `-Dproduct.name=_{server}` where `{server}` can be whatever you want, including an empty string. I chose `-Dproduct.name=AnonymousServer`. Click **Save**. The value you specify will be set in the **Server** field of the response header.

Change 2:

- Select **Configurations > server-config > Network Config > Network Listeners > http-listener-1**,  then click the **HTTP** tab in the right panel.
- Scroll down and uncheck the **XPowered By:** field and click **Save**.
- This will exclude the **X-Powered-By** field from the response header.

Change 3:

- Repeat *Change 2* above, but select **http-listener-2** (*security enabled*) instead of **http-listener-1** (*security not enabled*).

Finally, restart Glassfish, then connect to your application in a browser or a tool such as Postman, and verify that the response headers have changed. For example, here are before and after shots for a simple web application in Firefox, using
 its browser's developer tools. They show that after the configuration changes and restart:

- There is no longer an **X-Powered-By** response header field.
- The server name has been changed (to **AnonymousServer** in my case) in the **Server** field.

Before the changes:

[image: beforeChanges]

After the changes:

[image: afterChanges]